# High performance computing in .net/C#

Tags: .net, azure, mpi, hpc

I currently have a back testing framework written in C# that is used to back test trading strategies. It takes few hours to run on a single computer. I would like to use High Performance technology to cut the run time to few minutes.

I tried exploring HPC on Azure, but felt too tedious to configure, and didn't find enough knowledge base on using C# code to get started with HPC.

Are there other distributed computing technologies I could explore that would work well with C#/.NET ?

Comment: How about [MPI.NET](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/)?

Comment: How does MPI.NET compare to Microsoft HPC Pack

Answer (score 0):

A few questions that could point you to a solution:

Did you try multiple threads to compute?

Did you try run in Parallel (in case you have a loop)?

Did you try to split compute on multiple computers?

As you are using Azure, can you use multiple worker roles?

It's a little hard to answer your question, since we don't know what kind of compute your trying to do.

Comment: Currently using TPL to parallelize the task(s) on one computer. But, I have more than million inputs that TPL too is slow.

Comment: Also, distributed my compute across 3 computers. One is the controller, and two computers are nodes. They listen on a WCF port for inputs, and can take in multiple inputs. When done, then submit the result back to the controller to process, and accept more inputs.

Comment: I need to explore worker roles. I haven't tried this.

Comment: I basically have multiple different parameter combinations that need to be tried. The data comes from a centralized data cache. Each of the nodes have a WCF connection to the data repository.

Comment: @user977606 and how do you pull data from data cache?

Comment: WCF tcp endpoint. Have loaded 1-min bars (OHLC) data into cache.